# Problem with echo command

Tags: text-processing

I want read a file and after if there is one "KO" in the file ill break the program and print "KO". If there are all "OK" i want that at the end of the program it will display me "OK".
Here the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="res.txt"
righe=$(wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1}' )
riga=0
while [ $riga -lt $righe ]; do
let riga+=1
current=$(head -$riga $filename | tail -1)
if [ $current  == 'KO' ]; then
stampa="KO"
break
else
stampa="OK"
fi
done
echo $stampa
```

The problem is that when match all "OK" the program display me this:

```
./provaScript2.sh: line 12: [: too many arguments
./provaScript2.sh: line 12: [: ==: unary operator expected
OK
```

IOW I have a file like this:

```
OK
OK
OK
OK
KO
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

I want to print `OK` if it contains all "OK" and no "KO". i want print `KO` if it contains at least 1 "KO"

Comment: Can you let me see? (example pls)

Comment: first of all what you are trying to do ?

Comment: please format your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: i have a file like this:

ok
ok
ko
ko
ok
.
i want to print ok if it contains all "ok" and no "ko".
i want print ko if it contains at least 1 "ko".

Comment: do you have to read the file yourself? why not just `grep -q KO res.txt` and check the return code?

Comment: Your script does not correspond to the error message, there is no `[` on line 12. Please always cut and paste the exact code you are working with!  Also provide the contents of the file `res.txt`.  We don't know if it only contains a single line with a "OK" or "KO" or if there is other data in there as well.

Comment: @don_crissti `too many arguments` error appears when the input file has all that text in single line.. because `$current` variable is not quoted for `if [ "$current"  == 'KO' ]`

Comment: @don_crissti, am referring to 4th in edit history, where single line of input file `OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK KO OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK OK` was changed to multiple lines instead..

Comment: that's strange.. I can clearly see 3rd edit by OP showing sample res.txt as single line of OK/KO and 4th edit changing to multiple line OK/KO.. anyway, OP seems to have accepted simpler solution provided

Comment: @spasic Use **side-by-side-markdown** view instead of side-by-side.

Comment: yeah, side-by-side shows OP's edit as multi line as well.. sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: That's awful code. For a 100 line file you read (parts of) it 101 times.

Comment: What do you want to happen if some of the lines are neither `OK` nor `KO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -Fq "KO" res.txt
then
        echo "KO found, exiting.."
        exit
else
        echo "OK"
fi
```